# After Exchange Server Change Local EMails Bounce

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, email-bounces

We recently changed from an SBS 2003 to an SBS 2008 setup. In the process of migration, we have come across an issue whereby some users are receiving NDR emails when sending internal email.

```
IMCEAEX-_O=SAVEANDINVEST_OU=FIRST+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=David@sigrpglasgow.local
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found ##
```

The issue is that the 'SAVEANDINVEST' text isthe old domain name, but the recipients text points to the new one (@sigrpglasgow). How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you built a new domain with SBS2008 rather than migrating the old domain, is that right? It also sounds like these are old emails that are being replied to rather than new emails, right? If both of these statements are true then see this post:

[Deleted and Re-Added Exchange User Failure to Send](https://serverfault.com/questions/193913/deleted-and-re-added-exchange-user-failure-to-send)

Comment: Correct on both counts. Thank you, this solution looks like it will solve this for us.

Comment: Glad to help...